# How to create spark rdd for tree structure

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have a file with multiple types of records.  As below

```
File header 
       Group header 01
              Subgroup 01 s1 s2 
                Detail record 1 v1,v2,v3,v4
                Detail record 2 v1,v2,v3,v4
                Detail record 3 v1,v2,v3,v4
              Subgroup 02
                 Detail record 21
                 Detail record 22
              Subgroup 02 end
           Group header 01 end
 File header end
```

The file can have multiple groups and records. Each group header also has additional info.

Is there a way to create rdd without preprocessing ? 
The objective is to be able to analyse/query data in the file. For eg count of all v1 in group 01

Comment: In the existing system the way it works is these files are loaded into rdbms and made available on a web application. The web application is providing data filters , joins with lookup data and also display aggregate info after applying entitlement rules. I want to know if we can achieve below WebApplication --> Spark ---> RawFiles. The benefit of such an architecture will be 1) Performance 2) Scale 3) Rdbms can be removed